# Really struggling with adding values of grouped radio buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

This is for Winforms in Visual Studio C#. I have an assignment and I am struggling like crazy without help from the tutor. The course is online and not getting the help I need. Ok so. I have a form for a mock gym membership. For example the groups 1,2 & 3 need to add up at the end depending on which payment frequency was chosen

```
Group 1

Radio Button 1 Basic membership $10 per week,
Radio Button 2 Regular membership $15 per week,
Radio Button 3 Elite membership $20 per week

Group 2 

Radio Button 4 Pay Weekly, 
Radio Button 5 Pay Monthly,
Radio Button 6 Pay 3 Monthly

Group 3 Checkboxes

Extras
Gym tutorial videos $2 per week,
Personal trainer $50 per week
```

For example

I need the equation to display on a button click at the end in a text box.

What should an example code look like on the end Calculate button event to then show that in a text box?

Comment: I'm sure i've answered this recently..

Comment: Not from me nope Caius. I just asked now. 

Comment: True, not from you.. Just the specifics of the question are so similar/commonly posed academic exercise maybe..

Comment: State the formula you will work to. Discounts for monthly/yearly?

Comment: Create your RadioButtons and look at the CheckedChanged event. This is triggered when any of the RadioButtons are changed.  They can all call the same event handler. In the event handler, you need to perform the calculation.  Use the checkbox checked property to determine which checkboxes in group1 and group3 are set, that gives you the two values to add to get a weekly total, then check Group2 to see if you need to multiply it by 52 (yearly) or 52 / 13 (monthly) or as-is (weekly).  Display the result

Comment: This would be a scenario though the extras are different value with the 24/7 and videos weekly.

Comment: Scenario 1:
Membership type: basic
Duration: 3 months
Extras: 24/7, diet consultations
Payment method: bank
Frequency: weekly
Calculation 1:
Membership cost: $10 (for basic type)
Extra charges: $1 + $20 = $21 (for the extras above)
Total discount: $0.1. See the explanation below:
$0 (because it is basic membership) + (1 × 10 / 100) 
(because it is bank payment). So 1% on the base 
membership which is $10. So the result is $0.1.

Comment: Continued: Net membership cost: $30.9. See the explanation below:
This equals to membership cost + extra – total discount
$10 + $21 – $0.1 = 30.9
Regular payment amount: $30.9. See the justification below.
Because this is a weekly payment, then this cost will 
always be equal to Net membership cost

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make use of ternary:

```
var baseWeekPrice = 
  (basicRadioButton.Checked ? 10 : 0) +
  (regularRadioButton.Checked ? 15 : 0) +
  (premRadioButton.Checked ? 20 : 0) +
  (gymTutCheckBox.Checked ? 2 : 0) +
  (ptCheckBox.Checked ? 50 : 0);
```

Then a similar to derive 1, (52/12) or 52 (being the number of weeks in a week/month/year respectively) depending on which period RB is selected, and multiply them together

Note: monthly is a problem because some months have 4 weeks, some have 5. Maybe make it 4-weekly and resolve your headache

Comment: Cool do as long as I am naming the radio buttons and check boxes correctly this could work quite well:                                          var baseWeekPrice = 
  (basicRadioButton.Checked ? 10 : 0) +
  (regularRadioButton.Checked ? 15 : 0) +
  (premRadioButton.Checked ? 20 : 0) +
  (gymTutCheckBox.Checked ? 2 : 0);
  (ptCheckBox.Checked ? 50 : 0);

Comment: I fixed a typo; there are two `;`, one of them should be a +. You should always name your controls well.. some people post here with code that contains e.g. "button54", "textbox69" and I'm always somewhat dismayed that they've placed tens or hundreds of controls and never once thought "gee, if i called these something better I wouldn't have to constantly swap to the designer to remind myself whether the firstname is in textbox 27 or 37..". Replacing variable names with meaningless garbage is called obfuscation; a copy protection process that makes code hard to understand...